# I would like to write the content of 24 big files zipped into 1 file unzipped in order to count the number of distinct lines . Python

Tags: unix

I have tried this :

```
!gunzip file1.gz                                                          
!cat file1 >> data                                                          
!rm -Rf file1                                                           

!gunzip file2.gz                                                                  
!cat file2 >> data
!rm -Rf file2
```

but when doing that for file2 an error message is saying: "cat: write error: No space left on device" Knowing that I have to do that for 24 files, is there any alternative for me to have the content of all the files within one (the final file is supposed to have more than two million lines)

Comment: this isn't python, this is calling commands from a shell. And you don't have enough room on that drive, period (unless you want to create a compressed data file on the fly too)

Comment: I am working on jupyter. I will have to do a loop on python (using shell commands) for the 24 files instead of writing it 24 times.  I wanted to try first if it was working on the first files before implementing the loop...

Comment: if you don't have enough room on your disk, python or not, you're toast.

Comment: note that you could `gunzip -c file1.gz >> data` that would save one file creation & append step

Comment: sorting 24 big files will take some resources. Do you have an alternative like 1) count all lines and make an educated guess (counting unique lines in a sample or understanding your data) about the total
2) identify an unique key and only sort using that key
3) make use of a larger disk/partition

Comment: My unique key is for instance my first two columns of the files being concatenated

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to count unique lines, there's no need to create any files:

```
gunzip -c file1.gz file2.gz ... | sort -u | wc -l
```

or even

```
gunzip -c file*.gz | sort -u | wc -l
```

`gunzip -c` writes the unzipped files to stdout, one after another. `sort -u` sorts these, and filters out duplicates. `wc -l` finally counts the lines.

Comment: I need to count distinct lines in all the files being grouped

Comment: I have tried your suggestion :                                                                    
                                                                                                                        
       gunzip -c file*.gz | sort -u | wc -l
                                                                                                                        I have this as an error                                                                                    
    sort: write failed: /tmp/sortrlmHZ3: No space left on device

Comment: Hmm. Try `sort -u -S1000000` or some other large value (smaller than your main memory of course) to try and prevent it from creating temp files. The behaviour is not very well documented...

Comment: I have tried until -S1000000000000 The problem remains. Should I keep adding zeros until it works ?

Comment: Unless you have more than 1 TB of RAM, no ;)

Answer (score 0):

With unique data in the first two colums, `cut` them first. 
Perhaps with `cut -d"," -f1,2` or `cut -c1-16`. Use the correct `cut` in

```
gunzip -c file*.gz | cut -f 1,2 | sort -u | wc -l
```